# Jaspersoft iReport - how to set number of reducers for Hive query?

Tags: hadoop, jasper-reports, ireport, hive

I'm trying to run some reports using Jaspersoft iReport using Hive, which runs fine, except for situation when I try to set number of reducers for Hive query. I think this question might apply to general case of setting number of reducers using Hive JDBC.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put 2 SQL statements (or HiveQL statements) into the report query. This means you cannot use a query string like this:

```
set mapred.running.reduce.limit = 25;
SELECT name, phone_office, billing_address_city, billing_address_street, billing_address_country FROM accounts;
```

Normally I would think of putting a property like this into the JDBC connection. But as far as I can tell, Hive does not support this. But I think you could work around this by putting the "set" HiveQL statement as the main report query. Then put the "select" query as a subdataset. Here's a snippet from a report where I tested this idea:

```
<subDataset name="Accounts">
    <queryString language="HiveQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT name, phone_office, billing_address_city, billing_address_street, billing_address_country FROM accounts]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="phone_office" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="billing_address_city" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="billing_address_street" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="billing_address_country" class="java.lang.String"/>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="HiveQL">
    <![CDATA[set mapred.running.reduce.limit = 25]]>
</queryString>
```

I confirm that the report works like this. My subdataset fills a Table component just like you would expect. I don't have a simple way to confirm that it truly limited the number of reducers... but it should. (Please let us know if it does!)

Comment: This is nice, I'll try this, but this solution only sets 'global' number of reducers for every query used in this report, still I'll be unable to set this on per query basis.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In general, reports are based around a single query. Of course this isn't always the case. So I think it would be unusual that this limitation will impact you. Do you expect it to be important?

Comment: At the moment I have many reports with tables or charts (like 20-30 pages in PDF), it basically runs one query per table/chart, so it executes about 20-30 queries (from different datasources: Hive and RDBMS)

Comment: I think this might work using subreports, where I can setup per-subreport query that will set required number of reducers